# Running Helm in VirtualBox

Tags: haskell, opengl, virtualbox

I've written a game in Haskell using Helm, but I'm having problems when I try to run the game in my virtual box. I have tried running the game on other (Linux) computers and it works well, but when I run it in the virtual machine I get this error:

```
libGL error: pci id for fd 5: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
OpenGL Warning: glFlushVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerOutputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameteriNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinalCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glDeleteFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinishFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGenFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFenceivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glIsFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glSetFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glTestFenceNV not found in mesa table
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
```

Additionally I have been able to get Helm programs to run on the virtual machine before. The only difference is this one is much larger. How can I fix this error?

Comment: They filed a [defect report](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12941?cversion=0&cnum_hist=72) exactly like yours at the virtual box website. Maybe it can inform you on this.

Comment: It looks like that report was filed a year ago and it is supposedly fixed. I do have the newest version of virtualBox I think, so I would assume this issue is supposed to be fixed.